# Engle Granger test returns a 0 in matlab, while correlation factor is .80+. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: matlab, quantitative

Engle Granger test is giving me a ans = 0.
The correlation factor is: 0.8+

Does this imply the No cointegration hypothesis is true? i.e. as per my understanding that there is cointegration?

I am using matlab.

Thanks. I am completely new to matlab and this level of statistics/econometrics. I have been trading pairs using lower level stats and looking to improve the model.

Comment: I advice you to read a book on time series analysis. It is strongly recommended to know what you're doing in statistics.

Comment: @GoodGuyMike thanks, as noted in earlier question. Seeking one out right now. :)

Comment: To answer your question. Correlation and cointegration is basically not the same thing. I wish I could answer your other question as well on Johansens (I think that was the test you used), unfortunately I don't know that test well enough to ensure my credibility.

Comment: Thanks @GoodGuyMike, Reading up the literature and still can't figure out anything. Trying and trying again. :)